# Ideal way to handle integer overflows in Golang on different platforms

Tags: go, data-structures, integer-overflow, binary-heap

I'm implementing binary heap in golang. Given below is downheap function:

```
func (bh *BinaryHeap[V]) downheap(nodeIndex int) {
    for nodeIndex <= bh.length {
        priorIndex := nodeIndex
        leftIndex := nodeIndex << 1
        rightIndex := (nodeIndex << 1) + 1

        if leftIndex <= bh.length && bh.priorityFunc(bh.nodes[leftIndex].GetValue(), bh.nodes[priorIndex].GetValue()) {
            priorIndex = leftIndex
        }
        if rightIndex <= bh.length && bh.priorityFunc(bh.nodes[rightIndex].GetValue(), bh.nodes[priorIndex].GetValue()) {
            priorIndex = rightIndex
        }
        ...
```

While calculating *leftIndex* or *rightIndex* in above code, there is a potential cause of overflow (or negative value which makes program crash) if the number of elements in heap is close to *math.MaxInt* value (similar to recent bug in Java's *Arrays.BinarySearch* function)

- In case of 64-bit architecture:
  as *int* is equivalent to *int64*, I assume above implementation is practical.
- To support in 32-bit architecture: I have changed implementation as below due to potential cause of overflow error

```
func (bh *BinaryHeap[V]) downheap(nodeIndex int) {
    for nodeIndex <= bh.length {
        priorIndex := nodeIndex
        leftIndex := int64(nodeIndex) << 1
        rightIndex := (int64(nodeIndex) << 1) + 1

        if leftIndex <= int64(bh.length) && bh.priorityFunc(bh.nodes[leftIndex].GetValue(), bh.nodes[priorIndex].GetValue()) {
            priorIndex = int(leftIndex)
        }
        if rightIndex <= int64(bh.length) && bh.priorityFunc(bh.nodes[rightIndex].GetValue(), bh.nodes[priorIndex].GetValue()) {
            priorIndex = int(rightIndex)
        }
        ...
```

So, Is above implementation an ideal way to avoid the potential overflow error?

Comment: Why not explicitly use `int64` for `nodeIndex`?  It will compile correctly on 32-bit architectures.

Comment: @craigb thanks for quick reply and your answer makes sense to me. It didn't strike me that _int64_ type can be used an an index in slice. Using _int64_ is practical in this case. However, I couldn't understand the use of _int_ in golang  as it depends on the platform? Do I have to prefer _int64_ always to avoid these problems?

Comment: If you use `int` then it might map differently on 32 and 64 bit architectures; the only guarantee is that it is at least 32 bits.  But if you specify a particular size (eg, `int32` or `int64`) then it's guaranteed to be that size and won't depend on the platform.  See the [go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#int).